# Determination and CLASSPATH installation in LINUX

Tags: linux, unix, classpath, environment-variables, solaris

Determination and CLASSPATH installation in LINUX 
Excuse for a silly question (I ask to treat with understanding, I in linux the beginner and replenish knowledge as required) but how to define CLASSPATH in LINUX and where it is set. I tried to execute a command

```
root@one: echo $CLASSPATH
```

but in reply gave out only blank line.

Answer (score 0):

okay so in order to set the classpath
//to temporarly set the classpath use export CLASSPATH=someclass path

open your bashrc file in nano editor(default provided editor)

type nano ./.bashrc

and type the class as mentioned below

export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin

version may differ of your java

heres a link that may help you

[TRY THIS LINK](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/)